# PHP PDO/MySQL query not working properly

Tags: mysql

So I have this website where people can report some tracks. People can do so even tho they're not member of said website and if they're not members, the system will assign them a random "pseudo member number" (pmn from here on) in the style of "not_a_member_XXXX".

```
$query_claimed = "SELECT * FROM claims_archive WHERE t20pctID=:t20pctID AND member_name=:member_name AND member_email=:member_email AND (member_number=:member_number OR member_number LIKE '%not_a_member_%')"; 
$stmt = $con->prepare($query_claimed);
$stmt->bindParam(':t20pctID', $t20pctID);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_name', $member_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_number', $member_number);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_email', $member_email);
$stmt->execute();
```

In the testing period we have had some songs have been reported by the same person with a pseudo-number and some with a member number. My problem is that if I make a query with a pmn and the song exists with the same member name and e-mail but with another member number, the code will insert it instead of displaying a message in the style of "You have already claimed this song".

But if I do the query with the member number, then it will display the above message even if the record has it reported with a pmn.

I thought there was something wrong with my logic, but running the above query on phpMyAdmin, it does show the record if there is any matches. I have read about precedence, in case it applies here, and in case there's some operator order I should know about. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and I hope I made myself understood (English isn't my first or second language).

EDIT to add some info: although I haven't been able to identify a specific pattern for this issue, I have identified that it happens with this particular record.
[image]

Comment: Are your numbers stored as strings? If not you should bind the numeric parameters with `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Comment: unless you have exception throwing enabled, `prepare`, `bindParam` as well as `execute` will return `false`, if there's something wrong. You should probably check for that and look at `$con->errorInfo()` or `$stmt->errorInfo()` respectively.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: the numbers are strings because they can contain letters and '-' and '_'.

Comment: @Jakumi: thanks, I'll look into it. I don't have the exception throwing enabled tho. I just edited the OP with something I just noticed.

Comment: If you had exception throwing enabled, it would throw exceptions. Without it, you have to check return values. The record you provided doesn't look suspicious, I think.

Comment: @Jakumi: it turns out that I did have exception throwing enabled but then this is what I get on `$con->errorInfo()`: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )  and on `$stmt->errorInfo()`: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) LOL I don't get why it happens with this record and another similar one! But thanks for trying.

Comment: those errorinfos are saying "everything is okay". but apparently you got *some* kind of error, could you please provide the error message you get? or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: So after pondering for another few minutes, I can only come up with mistakes like "you're looking into the wrong database" and "your logic might be flawed" (like ... a song is "claimed" if an anonymous user (pmn) or the member itself has claimed it, but not other members, sounds weird). And retesting per phpmyadmin: ... is it really the exact same query? did you replace all the parameters you give in code with the actual values? Some structured testing of the symptoms should be your next step. Because what you describe shouldn't be possible, you should get the same results in code as in pma